# Where can I find a linux tar file for MySQLd to go with MySQL 5.5 and Python 2.7?

Tags: python, mysql

I have MySQL 5.5 and Python 2.7 installed on RPi. I just need to connect Python to MySQL. I keep reading about MySQLd and MySQL Connector. I think I'd prefer to go with mysqld from what I'm reading, but I can't find a tarball for a version that goes with my installation. I only find old version of mysqld or newer windows exe files. Please help. What am I missing???

Comment: You probably don't need to bother with that, you can just use a distro package as Vittal's answer strongly hints.

Answer (score 1):

Will this help?

```
> apt-cache search python-mysql
python-mysql.connector - pure Python implementation of MySQL Client/Server protocol
python-mysqldb - Python interface to MySQL
python-mysqldb-dbg - Python interface to MySQL (debug extension)
```

Comment: Reading the relevant man page will clarify what is going on here if necessary (`man apt-cache`).